# stopping form submit if the validation fails.

Tags: javascript, html

I am validating the dates in below function. If the validation fails, then the form should not get submitted. I tried returning false in form onsubmit but it still gets submitted. However, Validation is working fine and getting the alert that  I put in the function. Any help to stop submitting the form if validation fails.

```
<script>
  function dateCheck()
  {
      start = document.getElementById('name3').value;
      end = document.getElementById('name4').value;
      compare(start, end);
      document.getElementById('name4').focus();

  }

  function compare(sDate, eDate)
  {

      function parseDate(input) {
            var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);

            return new Date(parts[2], parts[0]-1, parts[1]); // months are 0-based
          }
       var parse_sDate = parseDate(sDate);
      var parse_eDate = parseDate(eDate);
       parse_sDate.setFullYear(parse_sDate.getFullYear() + 1);

      if(parse_eDate >= parse_sDate)
          {
          alert("End date should not be greater than one year from start date");
           return false;
          }
       return true;
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return dateCheck()">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="soname3" id="name3" size="15" readonly="readonly"> 
<img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name3','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12')" /></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="soname4" id="name4" size="15" readonly="readonly">
 <img src="../Image/cal.gif" id="" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal('name4','MMddyyyy','dropdown',false,'12'); " /> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you forget to add a return false statement to the DateCheck function?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just a comment:

If your listener passes a reference to the form, you can access the controls by name or ID:

```
<form onsubmit="return dateCheck(this)">
```

then:

```
function dateCheck(form) {
  var start = form.name3.value;
  ...
}
```

Note that you should declare variables, otherwise they will become global at the point they are assigned to. Also, you should check the values in the controls before passing them to the compare function (and display a message asking the user to enter a valid value if they aren't).

```
function dateCheck(form) {
  var start = form.name3.value;
  var end = form.name4.value;
  var valid = compare(start, end);

  if (!valid) form.name4.focus();

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Good validation.:)

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate all contributions above. I have just applied the suggestions above to solve my challenge & it works fine. Keeping it simple I use the following:

```
<form id="newuser" action="newuser.php" onsubmit="return pswderr(this)">
```

For the button I have

```
<input id='submit' type="submit" value="Login" onClick="return pswderr();">
```

My script is:

```
<script>
function pswderr() {
    var pswd1 = document.getElementById("newuserpswd").value;
    var pswd2 = document.getElementById("rptpswd").value;
    if (pswd1 !== pswd2) {
        document.getElementById("alarm").innerHTML = "Password and password  
        verification do not match. Retry";
        return false;
    } else {document.getElementById("alarm").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

use return on the onclick attribute in the form tag attribute onsubmit="**return** validateForm()" , if you return false in your validation function in javascript if the input is incorrect then you have to add return to your onclick attribute in order for it to execute .Hope it helped someone!

```js
<script>
        function validateForm(){
            var validation = false;
            var phonenumber = document.forms["enqueryForm"]["phonenumber"].value;
            if(phonenumber != 11) {
                alert("phonenumber is incorrect");
                //e.preventDefault();
                return false;
    
            }
        }
</script>
```

```html
<form class="form-style-5" action="BookingForm.php" method="post" id="bookingForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="enqueryForm">
<input type="tel" name="phonenumber" placeholder="your no.">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` is not going to stop the form from submit if its called in a subfunction e.g. `compare(sDate, eDate)`

so change your function to this

```
function dateCheck(e){

  var start = document.getElementById('name3').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('name4').value;
  if(compare(start, end)) {
    // no error submit i guess
    // return true ?
  } else {
    // error with date compare
    return false;
  }
  end.focus();

}
```

Comment: no. OP's approach is fine. no need to use `preventDefault()`. Return validation result on `onsubmit` event is perfectly OK .

Comment: The intention is to cancel submit only if validation fails. To do that, the submit listener simply returns *false*.

Comment: @RobG i think this should get the job done but i'm not sure if he still wants a return on success though

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used **pattern** in **input** field and also gave **maxlength**.

What worked with me was, remove Length attribute from input field

Comment: I was trying everything, when I could have just been returning false. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve the same thing using [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#your_form_id').ajaxForm( { beforeSubmit: dateCheck } ); 
});
```

Comment: Except that the OP isn't using jQuery or AJAX.

Comment: *sidenote:* i will rather prefer jQuery validation plugin, which includes the function of the plugin you quoted, as well as extended form validation features.

Answer (score -1):

```
     -    I hope this will help you : Just write this code on your Html/jsp page 
    <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            </head>

         - **Don't forget to add this on your html page**

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    //option A
                    $("regF").submit(function(e) { //regF is form id
                        alert('submit intercepted');
                        e.preventDefault(e);
                    });
                });
            </script>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is 5 years old and has been answered and accepted. I don't see much help in this answer. However, the objective was to stop the form submit if the date check failed. Your code will always stop the submit event. Please go through the answers first.