# Contact Form 7 AJAX Callback for diferents thank you pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, callback, contacts

I am using this js because I need depends if the user select a field diferents thank you pages.

```js
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7:mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '116' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {  
      var selection =  document.getElementById("selection").value;
  
      if (selection == "Problema") {
        location = '/contacto-gracias-producto/';
    } else if (selection == "Propuesta") {
        location = '/contacto-gracias-colaboracion/';
      }
  else if (selection == "Sugerencia") {
        location = '/contacto-gracias-sugerencia/';
  }
  else if (selection == "Consulta") {
        location = '/contacto-gracias-consulta/';
  }  
    }
}, false )
```

But the problem is: When I user click submit show a message "Please mark field required" but automatically redirect to the page thank you.

if the user don´t mark field required, the redirection should not be.

Any solution?

I need a conditional if all required field are marked.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stopping form submit if the validation fails.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646471/stopping-form-submit-if-the-validation-fails)

Comment: I have tried it but in my case it doesn´t work or maybe I don´t know implement it.

Comment: You'll have to show us how you tried to do it, otherwise we can't help you fix it